# Android WebView kotlin how to use input file

Tags: android, kotlin

I am a learning android developer trying to make my website into a simple App

While i was able to resolve most of my issue with this lovely community I am stuck at one part where input type file is not working any matter what I try. Please advice how to get input type file to work with kotlin

```
<input type="file">
```

my code till now is

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val progressBar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.MyProgress)
    val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
    myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    myWebView.settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(WebChromeClient())





    myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    myWebView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)
    myWebView.settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT)
    myWebView.settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    myWebView.settings.getAllowFileAccess();
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://example.com")
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onReceivedSslError(
            view: WebView,
            handler: SslErrorHandler,
            error: SslError
        ) {
            handler.proceed()
        }






        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap?) {

            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
            if (Uri.parse(url).host == "example.com") {
                // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                return false
            }
            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).apply {
                startActivity(this)
            }
            return true
        }


    })



}


}

<input type="file">
```

Comment: Webviews are generally used to load HTML webpages in android.It will not accept any files or pdf docs to load in it. What do you actually mean by input type = file?

Comment: i am referring to HTML input <input name="logo" type="file" accept="image/*">

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a project that needed file upload via the WebView. This is how we solved it. Hope it gets you in the right direction. Also note that `onActivityResult` is deprecated by now and could probably replaced by `registerForActivityResult`. [See this post for more details on that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

MainActivity.kt

```
companion object {
    /**
     * Request code for onActivityResult for when the user wants to pick an image
     * in the WebFragment
     */
    const val REQUEST_SELECT_FILE_IN_WEB_FRAGMENT = 328
}

/**
 * Used by [WebFragment] to upload photos to
 * the WebView. To do this, we need to catch onActivityResult after the user
 * selected the photo and pass it onto the WebView using this ValueCallback.
 */
private var uploadMessageReceiver: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? = null

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE_IN_WEB_FRAGMENT) {
        // This request was triggered from a webpage in WebFragment to select/upload a picture.
        // tell the uploadMessageReceiver about the selected image data and set it to null again.
        if (uploadMessageReceiver == null) return
        uploadMessageReceiver?.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data))
        uploadMessageReceiver = null
    }
}

// implemenation of the interface defined in WebFragment
override fun getMessageReceiver(): ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? {
    return uploadMessageReceiver
}

// implemenation of the interface defined in WebFragment
override fun setMessageReceiver(callback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?) {
    uploadMessageReceiver = callback
}
```

WebFragment.kt

```
private lateinit var uploadReceiver: UploadMessageReceiver

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    when (context) {
        is UploadMessageReceiver -> uploadReceiver = context
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Attached context must implement UploadMessageReceiver to allow image uploading in this WebView.")
    }
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


    with(binding.webView) {
        webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webChromeClient = BvbWebChromeClient()
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        settings.allowFileAccess = true
        settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        settings.databaseEnabled = true
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            loadUrl(arguments.url)
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Let the attached Activity implement this interface to catch the
 * onActivityResult after the user selected an image to upload (see [BvbWebChromeClient])
 */
interface UploadMessageReceiver {
    fun getMessageReceiver(): ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?
    fun setMessageReceiver(callback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?)
}

/**
 * This WebChromeClient is needed to allow the user to select an image that
 * he/she wants to upload to a web page.
 */
inner class BvbWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient() {

    /**
     * Used by the HTML Feedback form to upload an image.
     * Works tightly with [MainActivity.uploadMessageReceiver]
     */
    override fun onShowFileChooser(webView: WebView, filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>, fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams): Boolean {
        // make sure there is no existing message
        val uploadMessage = uploadReceiver.getMessageReceiver()
        if (uploadMessage != null) {
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null)
            uploadReceiver.setMessageReceiver(null)
        }
        uploadReceiver.setMessageReceiver(filePathCallback)
        val intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent()
        try {
            requireActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.REQUEST_SELECT_FILE_IN_WEB_FRAGMENT)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            uploadReceiver.setMessageReceiver(null)
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Cannot open file chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```