# OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, onactivityresult

I recently discovered that `onActivityResult` is deprecated. What should we do to handle it?

Any alternative introduced for that?

[image: Image showing code with onActivityResult striked out, indicating deprecation]

Comment: if I remove it an error lint appeared to add super call!

Comment: I don't know if there's ever been a deprecation that was un-deprecated but I'm holding out hope for `startActivityForResult`. This new way overly complicates the code and reduces readability.

Comment: It's hard to test the thing now :(

Comment: I can see why Google decided to go with this route, it's trying to decouple `startActivityForResult` from the view lifecycle. 

I just wished that there's a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) don't show it as deprecated.

Comment: Please check this official documentation. Hope this helps you. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: startActivityForResult also seems deprecated. Is it?

Comment: If anyone looking for Xamarin android solution : https://www.appliedcodelog.com/2022/02/startactivityforresult-onactivityresult.html

Comment: Anyone know at what api level this function was deprecated ?

Comment: @grolschie They do. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int)

Answer (score 782, accepted):

A basic training is available at [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Here is an example on how to convert the existing code with the new one:

**The old way:**

```java
public void openSomeActivityForResult() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 123) {
        doSomeOperations();
    }
}
```

**The new way (Java):**

```java
public void openSomeActivityForResult() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
    someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
}

// You can do the assignment inside onAttach or onCreate, i.e, before the activity is displayed
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // There are no request codes
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    doSomeOperations();
                }
            }
        });
```

**The new way (Kotlin):**

```
fun openSomeActivityForResult() {
    val intent = Intent(this, SomeActivity::class.java)
    resultLauncher.launch(intent)
}

var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // There are no request codes
        val data: Intent? = result.data
        doSomeOperations()
    }
}
```

**EDIT.** A better approach would be to make it more generalised so that we can reuse it. The snippet below is used in one of my projects but beware that it's not well-tested and may not cover all the cases.

**BetterActivityResult.java**

```java
import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCaller;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class BetterActivityResult<Input, Result> {
    /**
     * Register activity result using a {@link ActivityResultContract} and an in-place activity result callback like
     * the default approach. You can still customise callback using {@link #launch(Object, OnActivityResult)}.
     */
    @NonNull
    public static <Input, Result> BetterActivityResult<Input, Result> registerForActivityResult(
            @NonNull ActivityResultCaller caller,
            @NonNull ActivityResultContract<Input, Result> contract,
            @Nullable OnActivityResult<Result> onActivityResult) {
        return new BetterActivityResult<>(caller, contract, onActivityResult);
    }

    /**
     * Same as {@link #registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultCaller, ActivityResultContract, OnActivityResult)} except
     * the last argument is set to {@code null}.
     */
    @NonNull
    public static <Input, Result> BetterActivityResult<Input, Result> registerForActivityResult(
            @NonNull ActivityResultCaller caller,
            @NonNull ActivityResultContract<Input, Result> contract) {
        return registerForActivityResult(caller, contract, null);
    }

    /**
     * Specialised method for launching new activities.
     */
    @NonNull
    public static BetterActivityResult<Intent, ActivityResult> registerActivityForResult(
            @NonNull ActivityResultCaller caller) {
        return registerForActivityResult(caller, new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult());
    }

    /**
     * Callback interface
     */
    public interface OnActivityResult<O> {
        /**
         * Called after receiving a result from the target activity
         */
        void onActivityResult(O result);
    }

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Input> launcher;
    @Nullable
    private OnActivityResult<Result> onActivityResult;

    private BetterActivityResult(@NonNull ActivityResultCaller caller,
                                 @NonNull ActivityResultContract<Input, Result> contract,
                                 @Nullable OnActivityResult<Result> onActivityResult) {
        this.onActivityResult = onActivityResult;
        this.launcher = caller.registerForActivityResult(contract, this::callOnActivityResult);
    }

    public void setOnActivityResult(@Nullable OnActivityResult<Result> onActivityResult) {
        this.onActivityResult = onActivityResult;
    }

    /**
     * Launch activity, same as {@link ActivityResultLauncher#launch(Object)} except that it allows a callback
     * executed after receiving a result from the target activity.
     */
    public void launch(Input input, @Nullable OnActivityResult<Result> onActivityResult) {
        if (onActivityResult != null) {
            this.onActivityResult = onActivityResult;
        }
        launcher.launch(input);
    }

    /**
     * Same as {@link #launch(Object, OnActivityResult)} with last parameter set to {@code null}.
     */
    public void launch(Input input) {
        launch(input, this.onActivityResult);
    }

    private void callOnActivityResult(Result result) {
        if (onActivityResult != null) onActivityResult.onActivityResult(result);
    }
}
```

With the above approach, you still have to register it before or during launching the activity or fragment attachment. Once defined, it can be reused within the activity or fragment. For example, if you need to start new activities in most of the activity, you can define a `BaseActivity` and register a new `BetterActivityResult` like this:

**BaseActivity.java**

```java
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected final BetterActivityResult<Intent, ActivityResult> activityLauncher = BetterActivityResult.registerActivityForResult(this);
}
```

After that, you can simply launch an activity from any child activities like this:

```java
public void openSomeActivityForResult() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
    activityLauncher.launch(intent, result -> {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // There are no request codes
            Intent data = result.getData();
            doSomeOperations();
        }
    })
}
```

Since you can set the callback function along with the `Intent`, you can reuse it for any activities.

Similarly, you can also use other activity contracts using the other two constructors.

Comment: The new way looks unnecessarily complicated compared to the old way...

Comment: @drmrbrewer it removes the hassle of maintaining request codes and adds the ability to run tests. But I think its main problem is reusability. In my opinion `ActivityResultCallback` should be a part of `ActivityResultLauncher#launch()` so that we can reuse it for other purposes, eg., if I'd needed to check storage permissions for multiple actions, I could've use a single `ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()` for all of them. You could implement `ActivityResultCallback` in an attempt to solve this but that will be worse than the old way since you need something similar to request codes.

Comment: If my activity is starting 2 new activties for result then how would I differentiate it on onActivityResult?

Comment: The only convenience that I see is removing `result codes`. We had to add different constants for every activity. Sometimes we could mix and two result codes became equal. That could lead to different bugs.

Comment: @drmrbrewer, agree. They made an unnecessaty tool that broke usual multi-activity application (especially MVC). Now we have to create many callbacks instead of one `onActivityResult`. One activity contains 10 fragments, some of them can start other activities and return result. Before we simply returned `setResult()` in fragment and handled in `onActivityResult`. Now we have to create many callbacks.

Comment: The new way is way worse than the old. It breaks code modularity and forces you to use much more codelines to cover use cases of previous version. Deprecation should be used when you provide better API design, but at Google are deprecated stuff arbitrarely on the base of opinable decisions not technically justified that look based on few use cases.

Comment: @AndreaF Yeah, I was absolutely shocked when Google deprecated `ViewPager` in favour of `ViewPager2` which created more problems than solving anything.

Comment: @MuntashirAkon The list is very long, not talking about the SAF-maggedon, and not only on Android platform, and without any regard of backward compatibility of API interfaces, to the point that now I avoid to use any Google backed framework when possible, to avoid to face future hassles and waste of time in codebase migrations.

Comment: with help of lambda Java version can be reduced to Kotlin

Comment: What if activity is started by a library?

Comment: @YaMiN The library has to provide some sort of initialiser that must be called before or during activity creation or fragment attachment.

Comment: Was the dramatic change really necessary?! Google keeps changing things like some kind of baby diapers!

Comment: @ianhanniballake Correct, the results may not be delivered correctly due to lifecycle issues. However, since `BetterActivityResult` also needs to be initialised during or before fragment/activity creation, there might be a way to handle them internally within the class.

Comment: I'm surprised this API isn't called `startActivityForResult2`.  If you think working with result codes was tedious, just wait till you get a load of this hot mess.

Comment: I found this ZXing example of the new way https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/628

Comment: some times result code getting 0 instead -1

Comment: @drmrbrewer : what happens if we keep using the old way, it seems to be working still and not getting caught in code inspection : code maturity

Comment: Wow Google!, Thanks for this new complex way! the code was much easier before. improved result code against  re-usability...

Comment: Leaking 'this' in constructor of non-final class BaseActivity

Comment: JAVA users: It's more complicated. KOTLIN users: It's easier.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta It would be almost the same if you set 1.8 compatibility (lamda functions) in Java.

Comment: So instead of request code now you will have name of the function to call.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to migrate this deprecated code to the new method in Kotlin. However, I am still not understanding how you migrate the `requestCode` situation, when there is no replacement for it or at least I see no clear one. @ShubhamGupta I am using Kotlin. Care to explain how to replace dependence on `requestCode`?

Comment: A more handy piece of code as a generalized solution: https://github.com/pseusys/contribution/blob/main/kotlin/android/app/src/main/java/me/pseusys/contribution/ResultManagers.kt

Comment: There is no request code. How do I know where the result is coming from?

Comment: @Anga There is no concept of request code in the new design. It is expected that for each separate Intent, you will register a separate callback. This way, the activity/fragment knows where the result has to be sent. You can create alternatives like the one I've outlined above but as others have said, this new approach is totally useless and does not attempt to solve the actual issues.

Comment: @MilTy This, like `BetterActivityResult`, would fall into the same trap if the device configurations have changed while the activity is running. A solution is to reintroduce request codes but only internally. (I will update my post to fix the issue later on.)

Comment: @MuntashirAkon what kind of device configurations do you mean?

Comment: @MilTy Changing screen size, orientation, etc.

Comment: Change the existing working component which was super easy and working as expected and put it in the training/basic section, thanks google!

Comment: How i pass request code ?

Comment: I have an issue: I have two activities: from the first one starts the second one by calling this BetterActivityResult functionality. Everythings going well until I rotate the device screen after second activity was launched. In this case I get result.getResultCode() = RESULT_CANCELLED - ALWAYS!!! And ofcourse doSomeOperations(); is nevere run. How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Xamarin android solution https://www.appliedcodelog.com/2022/02/startactivityforresult-onactivityresult.html

Comment: This remindes me the camera2 api :)

Comment: Does anyone understand what is the benefit of the new API in terms of robustness? My tests show that when there's a configuration change after `startActivityForResult`,  `onActivityResult` is correctly called on the *new* Activity instance (not the destroyed one).

Comment: Benefits: 1: You can now launch activities for result from fragments and receive the results in fragments without going through the activity. 2: Instead of distinguishing requests with fallible INT codes you now have strongly typed classes. 3: You can have separate callbacks for separate requests, eliminating the need for switch-case in response handling,

There are probably more benefits. People should do some research before blindly upvoting "this looks more complicated" when it truly isn't (unless you're stuck in Java)

Comment: I used your "The new way (Java)" to pick a contact from the agenda and it works very well. Thanks

Comment: 'Who' even gets to decided that this is now the 'new way' to do it?

Comment: Anyone know at what api level this function was deprecated ?

Comment: @RonTLV: This is shipped with the AndroidX libraries, not the Android SDKs.

Comment: typical Google way of making perfectly well way of doing a thing unnecessarily complicated. I thought it was just me but good to know that others also feel the same.

Comment: Your code does not work in the same Activity, because it causes an infinite loop...

Answer (score 56):

From now, `startActivityForResult()` has been deprecated so use new method instead of that.

**Kotlin Example**

```kotlin
    fun openActivityForResult() {
        startForResult.launch(Intent(this, AnotherActivity::class.java))
    }


    val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { 
    result: ActivityResult ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val intent = result.data
            // Handle the Intent
            //do stuff here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 42):

There are 4 simple steps to follow while replacing the deprecated method `startActivityForResult(...)`.

1. In place of overridden method `onActivityResult(..)` -

   ```
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLaunch = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == 123) {
                        // ToDo : Do your stuff...
                    } else if(result.getResultCode() == 321) {
                        // ToDo : Do your stuff...
                    }
                }
   });
   ```

For multiple custom requests, append the condition as

```
if (result.getResultCode() == 123) {
..
} else if(result.getResultCode() == 131){
..
} // so on..
```

2. Imports :

   ```
    import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
    import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
    import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
    import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
   ```
3. In place of startActivityForResult(intent, 123), use

   ```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SampleActivity.class);
    activityResultLaunch.launch(intent);
   ```
4. In SampleActivity.java class, while returning back to source activity, code will remain the same like -

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   setResult(123, intent);
   finish();
   ```

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Thank you so much , your guide is quiet detailed

Answer (score 23):

In Java 8 it can be written alike this:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startActivityForResult = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    result -> {
        if (result.getResultCode() == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            Intent data = result.getData();
            // ...
        }
    }
);

Intent intent = new Intent( ... );
startActivityForResult.launch(intent);
```

Comment: How can I handle the multiple requestCode? Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like this approach!

Answer (score 21):

**In KOTLIN**
I changed my code

```
startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.MY_CODE_REQUEST)
```

and

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        when (requestCode) {
            Constants.MY_CODE_REQUEST -> {
            ...
}
```

to

```
registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    onActivityResult(Constants.MY_CODE_REQUEST, result)
}.launch(intent)
```

and

```
private fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, result: ActivityResult) {
    if(result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val intent = result.data
        when (requestCode) {
            Constants.MY_CODE_REQUEST -> {
            ...
```

I hope it works for you. :D

Comment: `onActivityResult` from your third code snippet on `registerForActivityResult` is deprecated.

Comment: @FilipeBrito onActivityResult is not an overwritten method, it is my own method, the name can be whatever ;)

Comment: the requestCode in the new way seems practically useless.

Comment: This is not the right approach . If you set the launch together with the registerForActivityResult we might run into initialization error. It's always better to create a variable first and do the registration there.

Answer (score 10):

For those whose fragments have more than one `requestCode`, and if you are not sure how to handle multiple results by those `requestCode`s, you need to understand that `requestCode` is useless in the new approach.

I imagine the old way you code like this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CODE) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO -> {
                // handle photo from camera
            }
            REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY -> {
                // handle image from gallery
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the new API, you need to implement the result of every requests in a separate `ActivityResultContract`:

```
val takePhotoForResult = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val intent = result.data
        // handle photo from camera
    }
}

val pickImageFromGalleryForResult = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val intent = result.data
        // handle image from gallery
    }
}
```

Then you need to start those activities/intents like this:

```
private fun startTakePhotoActivity() {
    takePhotoForResult.launch(Intent(requireActivity(), TakePhotoActivity::class.java))
}

private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
    val pickIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    pickIntent.setDataAndType(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        "image/*"
    )
    pickImageFromGalleryForResult.launch(pickIntent)
}
```

By doing this, you can get rid of hundreds of `const val REQUEST_` values in your project.

Comment: You get rid of hundreds of const val REQUEST_ values in your project by replacing them by hundreds of ActivityResultContracts. Where's the advantage?

Comment: Managing the values of these `REQUEST_` integers takes time, and integers can be used for different purposes, messing up the project. However `ActivityResultContracts` are used only one purpose guiding the developer to the right point. That makes the difference. @TheincredibleJan

Answer (score 9):

`onActivityResult`, `startActivityForResult`, `requestPermissions`, and `onRequestPermissionsResult` are [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha04) on `androidx.fragment` from `1.3.0-alpha04`, not on `android.app.Activity`.
Instead, you can use [`Activity Result APIs`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) with [`registerForActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultCaller#registerForActivityResult(androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract%3CI,%20O%3E,%20androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback%3CO%3E)).

Comment: where do you get to know about this " Activity Result APIs" with "registerForActivityResult"

whats the source ?

Comment: @Sumit As I linked change log on text _deprecated_, Android team said 'Please use the Activity Result APIs'

Answer (score 7):

Reference : [Kotlin - Choose Image from gallery](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch)

The Simplest Alernative I've found so far

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.id.activity_main)

    var ivPhoto = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivPhoto)
    var btnChoosePhoto = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnChoosePhoto)

    

val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent())  { uri: Uri? ->
            ivPhoto.setImageURI(uri)    // Handle the returned Uri
        }


    btnChoose.setOnClickListener {
        getContent.launch("image/*")
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: Why does your link point to "Launch an activity for result" if you label it "Kotlin - Choose Image from gallery"?

Answer (score 7):

**Here i explain the new way**

```
private val scan =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
        { result: ActivityResult ->
            if (result.resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {

                var selected_hub = result!!.data!!.getParcelableExtra<ExtendedBluetoothDevice>(Utils.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                Log.d(TAG,"RECONNECT PROCESS "+selected_hub!!.name)
                reconnect(selected_hub!!)

            }
        }
```

call this  from activity or fragment

```
private fun callScan() {
        val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), ScanningMeshDevices::class.java)
        scan.launch(intent)
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

The below code works in the Kotlin fragment to check the Bluetooth permission.

```
val intent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)

registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // There are no request codes
        val data: Intent? = result.data
        bluetoothAdapter.enable()
        Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Granted: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        dynamicButton()
    }
    else{Toast.makeText(context, "You have to enable bluetooth to use this app.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
    
}.launch(intent)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution:

In our project, we had 20+ occurrences of startActivityForResult (and onActivityResult).

We wanted to change the code as little as possible (and keep using request codes), while introducing an elegant solution for future use.

Since lots of us, developers, use **BaseActivity** concept - why not take advantage of it?

Here is BaseActivity:

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    private var requestCode: Int = -1
    private var resultHandler: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        registerForActivityResult()
    }

    private fun registerForActivityResult()
    {
        if (shouldRegisterForActivityResult())
        {
            resultHandler = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->

                onActivityResult(result.data, requestCode, result.resultCode)
                this.requestCode = -1
            }
        }
    }

   fun startActivityForResult(requestCode: Int, intent: Intent)
   {
       this.requestCode = requestCode
       resultHandler?.launch(intent)
   }

   protected open fun onActivityResult(data: Intent?, requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int)
   {
       // For sub activities
   }

   protected open fun shouldRegisterForActivityResult(): Boolean
   {
      // Sub activities that need the onActivityResult "mechanism", should override this and return true
       return false
   }
}
```

Here is SubActivity:

```
class SubActivity : BaseActivity()
{
    companion object
    {
        private const val SOME_REQUEST_CODE = 300
    }

    private fun testActivityResult()
    {
        val intent = Intent(this, OtherActivity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(SOME_REQUEST_CODE, intent)
    }

    override fun shouldRegisterForActivityResult(): Boolean
    {
        return true
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(data: Intent?, requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int)
    {
        if (requestCode == SOME_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            // Yes!
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 4):

I figured how to do it properly from a Fragment in Kotlin, to capture an image and handle returned bitmap. It is pretty much the same in other cases too.

First, you have to register the fragment to listen for the activity results. This has to be done before initiating the fragment, which means creating a member variable instead of initiating within onCreate function.

```
class DummyFragment : Fragment() {

  //registering fragment for camera listener
  private val takePhoto = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
  ) {
    if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      val imageBitmap = it.data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
      // do your thing with the obtained bitmap
    }
  }

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  }

}
```

Then, call the camera intent as you would normally do. And use this above-created variable to launch the intent.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  someRandomButton.setOnClickListener {
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    takePhoto.launch(takePictureIntent)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My goal was to reuse the current implementation of the `startActivityForResult` method with minimum code changes. For that purpose, I made a wrapper class and interface with an onActivityResultFromLauncher method.

```
interface ActivityResultLauncherWrapper {

    fun launchIntentForResult(activity: FragmentActivity, intent: Intent, requestCode: Int, callBack: OnActivityResultListener)

    fun unregister()

    interface OnActivityResultListener {
        fun onActivityResultFromLauncher(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
    }
}

class ActivityResultLauncherWrapperImpl : ActivityResultLauncherWrapper {
    private var weakLauncher: WeakReference<ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>>? = null

    override fun launchIntentForResult(
            activity: FragmentActivity,
            intent: Intent,
            requestCode: Int,
            callBack: ActivityResultLauncherWrapper.OnActivityResultListener
    ) {

        weakLauncher = WeakReference(
                activity.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
                    callBack.onActivityResultFromLauncher(requestCode, result.resultCode, result.data)
                }
        )

        weakLauncher?.get()?.launch(intent)
    }

    override fun unregister() {
        weakLauncher?.get()?.unregister()
    }
}
```

I am using Dagger in my project and I injected the wrapper where it is needed

```
@Inject
lateinit var activityResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncherWrapper
```

But the wrapper also can be instantiated directly:

```
val activityResultLauncher = ActivityResultLauncherWrapper()
```

then you have to change the `startActivityForResult` method with `launchIntentForResult`. Here is example where it is called from a fragment:

```
activityResultLauncher.launchIntentForResult(
        requireActivity(),
        intent,
        REQUEST_CODE_CONSTANT,
        object: ActivityResultLauncherWrapper.OnActivityResultListener {
            override fun onActivityResultFromLauncher(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
                /*do something*/
            }
        }
)
```

You will receive the result in the anonymous object.
You could use `OnActivityResultListener` in a Fragment or an FragmentActivity if you implement the Interface and refactor the current implementation like this:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(), OnActivityResultListener {
   
 ...
    
override fun onActivityResultFromLauncher(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {/*do somthing*/}

 ...

}
```

As we know, the Kotlin class ActivityResultLauncherWrapper could be used in java code as well. There are java classes in my project as well. There is an example with implementation of the callback interface in a Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnActivityResultListener {
    
...

    @Inject
    ActivityResultLauncherWrapper activityResultLauncher;
//ActivityResultLauncherWrapper activityResultLauncher = new ActivityResultLauncherWrapper()

...

public void launnchActivity(@NotNull Intent intent) {
        activityResultLauncher.launchIntentForResult(requireActivity(), intent, REQUEST_CODE_CONSTANT, this);
    }

...

 @Override
    public void onActivityResultFromLauncher(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {/*do somthing*/}
...
}
```

I hope this helps to build the solution for your case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use extension functions for Koltin. For example:

```
//random utils file
fun Fragment.buildGetContentRequest(function: (Uri) -> Unit): ActivityResultLauncher<String> {
    return this.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) {
        function(it)
    }
}

fun Fragment.buildTakePhotoRequest(function: (Boolean) -> Unit): ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> {
    return this.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) {
        function(it)
    }
}

fun Fragment.buildSelectMultipleContentRequest(function: (MutableList<Uri>?) -> Unit): ActivityResultLauncher<String> {
    return this.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetMultipleContents()) {
        function(it)
    }
}
```

And then in your fragment something like this

```
//your actual fragment logic
class YourFragment : Fragment() {
    //we can assign our request in init process
    private val mRequestSelectFiles = buildSelectMultipleContentRequest { 
        onFilesSelected(it) 
    }


    fun onSelectFiles() {
        val mime = "*/*"
        mRequestSelectFiles.launch(mime)
    }

    fun onFilesSelected(list: MutableList<Uri>?) {
        //your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to add these dependencies :-
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6"

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was trying to use the intent I was moving directly to the next activity without using the Google Sign In.

What worked for me :

`Inside OnCreate set the onClickListener for the sign-in button :`

```
     btnSignIn.setOnClickListener {
        signIn()
        }

    private fun signIn() {
        val intent = client.signInIntent
        mainActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
    }
```

In the above code I was writing the intent to go to the next activity but I had to write `client.signInIntent`

```
    var mainActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result ->

        if(result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            val data = result.data
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
                Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.id)
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This was what how I replaced multiple requestCodes (put this code in your Activity):

```
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launchCameraActivity = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    Bitmap photoBitmap;
                    if(data != null && data.getExtras() != null){
                        photoBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        if (photoBitmap != null) {
                            dataModel.setPhoto(ImageUtil.convert(photoBitmap));
                            imageTaken.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            imageTaken.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launchCameraAndGalleryActivity = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                
                Intent data = result.getData();
                Uri imageUri;
                if (data != null) {
                    imageUri = data.getData();
                    InputStream imageStream;
                    try {
                        imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                        Bitmap photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        dataModel.setOtherImage(ImageUtil.convert(photoBitmap));
                        documentImageTaken.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        documentImageTaken.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap);
                    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I launch the activities like this:

```
                    Intent photoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                launchCameraAndGalleryActivity.launch(photoIntent );

Intent galleryIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    launchCameraActivity.launch(galleryIntent);
```

Comment: Great !!!
Alternative for Image picker

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `onActivityResult` is deprecated in the super class but you did not mention the super class name and `compileSdkVersion` here in your question.

In Java and Kotlin every class or method could be marked as deprecated simply by adding `@Deprecated` to it so check your super class you may extend a wrong class.

When a class is deprecated all of its methods are deprecated too.

To see a quick solution click on deprecated method and press `Ctrl+Q` in Android studio to see documentation of method there should be a solution for it.

---

In my project using `androidx` and API 29 as `compileSdkVersion`, this method is NOT deprecated in activities and fragments

Comment: Since now, in project, using androidx and API 29 as compileSdkVersion, this method is deprecated too.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin version of [@Muntashir Akon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4147849/muntashir-akon) solution

```
class BetterActivityResult<Input, Result> private constructor(
  caller : ActivityResultCaller,
  contract : ActivityResultContract<Input, Result>,
  var onActivityResult : ((Result) -> Unit)?,
) {

private val launcher : ActivityResultLauncher<Input> =
   caller.registerForActivityResult(contract) { onActivityResult?.invoke(it) }

  /**
   * Launch activity, same as [ActivityResultLauncher.launch] except that it 
   * allows a callback
   * executed after receiving a result from the target activity.
   */
  /**
   * Same as [.launch] with last parameter set to `null`.
   */
  @JvmOverloads
  fun launch(
     input : Input,
     onActivityResult : ((Result) -> Unit)? = this.onActivityResult,
  ) {
    this.onActivityResult = onActivityResult
    launcher.launch(input)
  }

  companion object {
  /**
   * Register activity result using a [ActivityResultContract] and an in-place 
   * activity result callback like
   * the default approach. You can still customise callback using [.launch].
   */
  fun <Input, Result> registerForActivityResult(
    caller : ActivityResultCaller,
    contract : ActivityResultContract<Input, Result>,
    onActivityResult : ((Result) -> Unit)?,
  ) : BetterActivityResult<Input, Result> {
    return BetterActivityResult(caller, contract, onActivityResult)
  }

  /**
   * Same as [.registerForActivityResult] except
   * the last argument is set to `null`.
   */
  fun <Input, Result> registerForActivityResult(
    caller : ActivityResultCaller,
    contract : ActivityResultContract<Input, Result>,
  ) : BetterActivityResult<Input, Result> {
    return registerForActivityResult(caller, contract, null)
  }

  /**
   * Specialised method for launching new activities.
   */
  fun registerActivityForResult(
    caller : ActivityResultCaller,
  ) : BetterActivityResult<Intent, ActivityResult> {
    return registerForActivityResult(caller, StartActivityForResult())
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way to do this is in 3 steps. (Considering you have a startActivityForResult(0 and onActivityResult())

1. create a variable in the form `var resultLauncher:ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>`
2. create a private function where you initialize the resultLauncher in this basic format

```
resultLauncher=registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){result ->  

// copy paste the code from the onActivityResult replacing resultcode to result.resultCode  

if(result.resultcode==Activity.Result_OK){
val data=result.data // this data variable is of type intent and you can use it 

}else{
//code if you do not get the data 
}
}
```

3. Go to the line with `startActivityForResult()` and replace it with the line `resultLauncher.launch(intent)`

Answer (score 2):

[dor506](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66424889/10382935) answer worked for me as i use BaseActivity in most of my projects so it is easier for me to change the code in single file rather than all my activites. I have written the java version of this code.

BaseActivity code :

```
private int requestCode = -1;
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> resultHandler = null;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;

    registerForActivityResult();
}
  private final void registerForActivityResult() {
    if (shouldRegisterForActivityResult()) {
        this.resultHandler = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback() {

            public void onActivityResult(Object var1) {
                this.onActivityResult((ActivityResult)var1);
            }

            public final void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                Intrinsics.checkNotNullExpressionValue(result, "result");
                AppActivityClass.onActivityResult(result.getData(), AppActivityClass.this.requestCode, result.getResultCode());
                AppActivityClass.this.requestCode = -1;
            }
        });
    }
}

public final void startActivityForResult(int requestCode, Intent intent) {
    this.requestCode = requestCode;
    if (resultHandler != null) {
        resultHandler.launch(intent);
    }
}

protected static void onActivityResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, int resultCode) {
}

protected Boolean shouldRegisterForActivityResult() {
    return false;
}
```

Now in any activity use this code like this:

```
 @Override
protected Boolean shouldRegisterForActivityResult() {
    return true;  // this will override the baseactivity method and we can use onactivityresult
}

  private void someMethod(){
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext,SomeOtherClassActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(101,i);
}

  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 101) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //revert from called class
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Sharing solution that I've found**

First, register this activity for result using `registerForActivityResult`
This will return an object of type `ActivityResultLauncher<Intent!>`
Like this,

```
private val getResult =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) {
            if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val value = it.data?.getStringExtra("input")
            }
        }
```

Now where ever we want to launch activity for result we can use `getResult.launch(intent)`

Comment: Simple, easy to follow example - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Combine with the above answer, I have a approach that compatible with the old way *startActivityForResult()* keep using **requestCode** without changing old code structure:

**ActivityLauncher.class**

```
public class ActivityLauncher {

private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher;
private ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> activityResultCallback;

private ActivityLauncher(@NonNull ActivityResultCaller caller,
                         @NonNull ActivityResultContract<Intent, ActivityResult> contract,
                         @Nullable ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> activityResultCallback) {
    this.activityResultCallback = activityResultCallback;
    this.launcher = caller.registerForActivityResult(contract, this::onActivityResult);
}

public static ActivityLauncher registerActivityForResult(
        @NonNull ActivityResultCaller caller) {
    return new ActivityLauncher(caller, new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), null);
}

public void launch(Intent intent, @Nullable ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> activityResultCallback) {
    if (activityResultCallback != null) {
        this.activityResultCallback = activityResultCallback;
    }
    launcher.launch(intent);
}

private void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
    if (activityResultCallback != null) activityResultCallback.onActivityResult(result);
}

public interface OnActivityResult {
    void onActivityResultCallback(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
}
```

}

Code in **BaseActivity.java**

```
private final ActivityLauncher activityLauncher = ActivityLauncher.registerActivityForResult(this);

public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, ActivityLauncher.OnActivityResult onActivityResult) {
    activityLauncher.launch(intent, result -> onActivityResult.onActivityResultCallback(requestCode, result.getResultCode(), result.getData()));
}
```

And finally in each **Activity** that extends **BaseActivity**, implements **ActivityLauncher.OnActivityResult** and change the name of override function "onActivityResult" to "onActivityResultCallback". Also rember to remove *super.onActivityResult()*

How to use: startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode, this)

Answer (score 1):

startActivityForResult and onActivityResult is deprecated in android 10 API 30 now we have a new way to get the result using  registerForActivityResult

```
resultContract =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // There are no request codes
            val country = result.data?.getParcelableExtra<Country>("Country")
            showLiveDemoDialogue(country)
        }
    }
```

and to launch activity

```
val intent = Intent(this, CountriesListActivity::class.java)
        resultContract.launch(intent)
```

but you should register before you call launch And launch wherever you want.
otherwise, you will get this exception

```
attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you implement your base Activity like this, you may continure using startActivityForResult in old fashion.
The only limitation is you will have to use setResult(result, intent) to set the result within your activity.
The key is to let the result carry the request code back to the result consumer.

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityLauncher;
    protected static String ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = "my.activity.request.code";
    protected _originalIntent; 

    public void launchActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode){
        intent.putExtra(UGM_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE, requestCode);
        activityLauncher.launch(intent);
    }

    //
    //In order to be signature compatible for the rest of derived activities, 
    //we will override the deprecated method with our own implementation!
    //
    @SuppressWarnings( "deprecation" )
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode){
        launchActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    _originalIntent = getIntent();
        //set the default result
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, _originalIntent);

        activityLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                Intent intent = result.getData();
                int requestCode = intent.getIntExtra(ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE, -1);
                MyBaseActivity.this.onActivityResult(requestCode, result.getResultCode(), intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simple Example of registerForActivityResult for both StartActivityForResult & RequestMultiplePermissions from Activity and Fragment [in Kotlin]

### Requesting activity for result from Activity

```
registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) { activityResult ->
    if (activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //...
    }
}
```

### Check out [ActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResult)

Requesting for permissions from Activity?

```
registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()
) {
    //it: Map<String, Boolean>
}
```

### From Fragment?

Use same methods but make sure you put these implementations in `initialization, onAttach(), or onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using SMS consent API then use the following code (Kotlin):

```
resultLauncher.launch( consentIntent
                            )

    var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // There are no request codes
    //    val data: Intent? = result.data
        val message = result.data?.getStringExtra(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE)
        getOtpFromMessage(message)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using kotlin extension to make it very simple. Add below extensiton fucntion in your **Extenstions.kt** file:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.startForResult(intent: Intent,
    onResult: (resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) -> Unit
) {
    this.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {result ->
        onResult(result.resultCode, result.data)
    }.launch(intent)
}
```

Now, inside any activity that inherits AppCompatActivity, you can use below simple code:

```
val i = Intent(this, TargetActivity::class.java)
startForResult(i) { resultCode, data ->
   //put your code here like:
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      //your code here...
      }
   }
}
```

**Update**
Above implementaion may cause below exception:
*java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner xxxx is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.*

So registerForActivityResult should be called in advance for example before onCreate. Here is the alternative solution.

Add below extensiton fucntion in your **Extenstions.kt** file:

```
fun AppCompatActivity.registerForResult(onResult: (resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) -> Unit):
        ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> {
    return this.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        onResult(result.resultCode, result.data)
    }
}
```

Now, inside any activity that inherits AppCompatActivity, you can use below simple code:

1. **Define a class memeber variable** for every action requires result

> 

```
private val myActionResult = registerForResult { resultCode, data ->
   //put your code here like:
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      //your code here...
      }
   }
}
```

2. **Launch the action**

> 

```
val i = Intent(this, TargetActivity::class.java)
myActionResult.launch(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the answers by [muntashir akon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4147849/muntashir-akon) and [abhijeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12256844/abhijeet), you can modify the new format to work like the old format by passing values in the intent, for example:

```
// calling class
....
val i = Intent(this@GEBShopActivity, BarcodeScannerActivity::class.java)
when(loadedFragment){   
   is ShopHomeFragment      -> { i.putExtra("myapp.result.code", CODE_ACTIVITY_SCAN_LIST_MAINT) }
   is ShopListFragment      -> { i.putExtra("myapp.result.code", CODE_ACTIVITY_SCAN_LIST_MAINT) }
   is ShopItemMaintFragment -> { i.putExtra("myapp.result.code", CODE_ACTIVITY_SCAN_ITEM_MAINT) }
   is ShopPriceFragment     -> { i.putExtra("myapp.result.code", CODE_ACTIVITY_PRICE_CAPTURE) }
   is ShopCompareFragment   -> { i.putExtra("myapp.result.code", CODE_ACTIVITY_PRICE_CAPTURE) }
}
shopFragmentLauncher.launch(i)
....
```

```
// called class
....
val resultIntent = Intent()
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putStringArrayList("scanned_barcodes", scanned_barcodes)
bundle.putInt("scan_count", scan_count)
resultIntent.putExtras(bundle)
resultIntent.putExtra("myapp.result.code", intent.getIntExtra("myapp.result.code", 0))
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent)
....
```

This will allow you to keep the class called the same with just the one extra line to add your original called result code. Also allows you to create a reusable launcher instance.

Answer (score 0):

**2023** Kotlin Answer to get an `Uri`.

An example for those who are searching for a way to **fetch an image** from the **image library** and handle the `Uri` because `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)` is **crossed out/deprecated**

[image]

I got this answer from [google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) and it works.

```
val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
    // Handle Uri
}
```

FYI you should be able to use this to get any `Uri`, not just for images. Here it is used below.

```
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ...

        binding.selectPhotoButton.setOnClickListener {
            selectPhoto()
        }
    }

    fun selectPhoto() {

        getContent.launch("image/*") // *** What Google said to do to launch the image library ***
    }

    // *** This is what Google posted to handle the Uri ***
    val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->

        // Handle the returned Uri

        binding.myImageView.setImageURI(uri)
    }
}
```