# onActivityResult() deprecated for AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult

I am using **in-app updates** for android and as [per the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#kotlin), they are using onActivityResult to handle app behaviour incase the update is interrupted.

This is my function that is called from my fragment:

```
private fun startImmediateUpdate(appUpdateInfo: AppUpdateInfo) {
    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
        appUpdateInfo,
        AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
        requireActivity(),
        Constants.CODES.APP_UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE
    )

}
```

This is how i am handling results in parent activity

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    when (requestCode) {
        Constants.CODES.APP_UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE -> {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK || resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED || resultCode == ActivityResult.RESULT_IN_APP_UPDATE_FAILED) {
                //Do whatever i want to
            }
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Now super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data) is deprecated. **Things are working fine for now** but i am worried the app will crash if its wiped out completely

What can i do to replace onActivityResult()? I have looked into         registerForActivityResult() but could not find anything that suits my usecase.

Comment: [OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62671106/3290339). You should go as per [Getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: @Onik i am not starting any activity on my own. Its a built in function used by appUpdateManager, although works in the similar fashion as startActivityForResult() , but i just want to handle the results. Not launching anything on my own.

Comment: Check this on google documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#separate.
Maybe will help you

Comment: @HashirAli Any update?

Comment: Nothing positive so far.

Comment: Please see [this tweet](https://twitter.com/ianhlake/status/1532782435447951361) by Ian Lake which helped me implement a solution that uses `registerForActivityResult`. However it's not that simple as there is no sample and the documentation is quite sparse.

Comment: This was finally added in version `2.1.0` of the library. Please see my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72726406/416029).

Answer (score 11):

**Update (June 2023):**

Since version [2.1.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/release-notes-in_app_updates#2-1-0) of the In-App Updates library, which was released in May 2023, an overload of [startUpdateFlowForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/appupdate/AppUpdateManager.html#startUpdateFlowForResult(com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateInfo,%20com.google.android.play.core.common.IntentSenderForResultStarter,%20com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateOptions,%20int)) that accepts an `IntentSenderForResultStarter` was finally added.

---

**Old answer (before version 2.1.0):**

As Ian Lake [mentioned](https://twitter.com/ianhlake/status/1532782435447951361) there is a solution that uses [IntentSenderForResultStarter](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/common/IntentSenderForResultStarter).

First of all in your Activity, create a [ActivityResultLauncher](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultLauncher):

```kotlin
private val updateFlowResultLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
    ) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Handle successful app update
        }
    }
```

Now start the update flow as follows:

```kotlin
fun startUpdate(
    appUpdateInfo: AppUpdateInfo,
    requestCode: Int,
) {
    val starter =
        IntentSenderForResultStarter { intent, _, fillInIntent, flagsMask, flagsValues, _, _ ->
            val request = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intent)
                .setFillInIntent(fillInIntent)
                .setFlags(flagsValues, flagsMask)
                .build()

            updateFlowResultLauncher.launch(request)
        }

    appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
        appUpdateInfo,
        AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE,
        starter,
        requestCode,
    )
}
```

Comment: If you're using `Compose` this may be helpful: https://gist.github.com/tadfisher/e1bd46bfcabf92f96278bf8d25da6d0e

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue and I see that one possibility is to rewrite to use the [startUpdateFlow call](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/appupdate/AppUpdateManager#startUpdateFlow(com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateInfo,%20android.app.Activity,%20com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateOptions)) instead.

Personally, I think this is not worth doing, so I will ignore this specific deprecation warning instead and wait/hope for Android/Google to make a method where we can pass an `ActivityResultLauncher` instead.

Comment: as of 22-DEC-21, no update from google yet they want us to target sdk 30 at min and use scopedstorage and what not

Comment: This was finally added in version `2.1.0` of the library. Please see my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72726406/416029).

Answer (score -1):

The New Way

```
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
            && (appUpdateInfo.clientVersionStalenessDays() ?: -1) >= 2
            && appUpdateInfo.updatePriority() >= updatePriority
            && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
        ) {
            appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                appUpdateInfo,
                AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                this,
                updateCode
            )
            openActivityForResult()
        }
    }
}

private fun openActivityForResult(){
    resultUpdate.launch(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
}

var resultUpdate = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result->
    if (result.resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "App Update failed, please try again on the next app launch.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I'm waiting for an official support of the new API with `ActivityResultLauncher` as Anders Ullnæss wrote above.