# Android In-app Update not working when trying to resolve onActivityResult deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to implement Android In-App Update, but the code tells me that the call to `onActivityResult` is deprecated.

I have tried the suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72726406/5587982) to solve it.

This is my code into `MainActivity`:

```
private val updateFlowResultLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
    ) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Handle successful app update
        }
    }

private fun checkAppUpdate() {
    val starter =
        IntentSenderForResultStarter { intent, _, fillInIntent, flagsMask, flagsValues, _, _ ->
            val request = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intent)
                .setFillInIntent(fillInIntent)
                .setFlags(flagsValues, flagsMask)
                .build()

            updateFlowResultLauncher.launch(request)
        }
    appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this)
    appUpdateManager.registerListener(installStateUpdatedListener)
    val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo: AppUpdateInfo ->
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
            && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)
        ) {
            try {
                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    appUpdateInfo,
                    AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE,
                    starter,
                    UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE
                )
            } catch (e: SendIntentException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun checkNewAppVersionState() {
    appUpdateManager
        .appUpdateInfo
        .addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo: AppUpdateInfo ->
            if (appUpdateInfo.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
                popupAlerter()
            }
        }
}

private fun popupAlerter() {
    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(
        findViewById(android.R.id.content),
        "Nueva versión descargada, por favor reinicia",
        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
    )
    snackbar.setAction("REINICIAR") { view: View? -> appUpdateManager.completeUpdate() }
    snackbar.setActionTextColor(
        ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent)
    )
    snackbar.show()
}

private fun unregisterListener() {
    appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(
        installStateUpdatedListener
    )
}
```

I have uploaded an internal test with a version older than the version published in the Play Store, but it does not work.

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The new way to do it would be like this.

```
fun openSomeActivityForResult() {
val intent = Intent(this, SomeActivity::class.java)
resultLauncher.launch(intent)
}

var resultLauncher =  registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    // There are no request codes
    val data: Intent? = result.data
    doSomeOperations()
 }
}
```

You would have to tweak it to fit your code.