# Android Security Vulnerability - Intent Redirection in Fragment Activity OnActivityResult

Tags: android, google-play, fragment, android-security, prelaunch

Recently, My app update got rejected due to Security Vulnerability INTENT REDIRECTION. And as per Google Play console - Security Alerts. Following is the error.

Your app contains an Intent Redirection vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details.

```
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult
```

I went through remediation document as well. Still unable to identify which library or code is causing the issue. Any way to identify it? It will be of great help. Thanks.

I have also request Google developer support to provide specific library or class if possible.

Comment: For whoever, facing the problem. Currently, I am following this approach to resolve and yet to re-upload updated build to Play store.  1) Update Paytm SDK to 1.5.3 if you have not already done. We've received confirmation mail from them that few of their merchants faced the same issue and it has been handled new SDK. 2) Also, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative and follow best practices to check package and class name of component before startActivity. 3) Update all libraries if any. Will update shortly.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm also facing the same issue, any update on the solution?

Comment: After updating to PayTm All-in-one SDK, the above issue got resolved but facing the same INTENT_REDIRECT with a different line of code.

Comment: Hi @shakunthalaMK, were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: yes. We upgraded all our dependencies. One of the Payment gateway SDK was causing the issue.