# OnActivityResult method is deprecated, how do I use registerForActivityResult from a Menu's onOptionItemselected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult

I'm using Kotlin. I have beent trying to choose a folder to create a file in it and export Data from my Database into said file.  But now it showed me, that startActivityForResult is deprecated 
I have read the Question:
[OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative/63654043)
, but sadly, I couldn't see how you would implement that in a Optionsmenu, to open a Action_Create_Document for a Data-Export.

As a non-native Speaker, i also had quite a bit of trouble to understand the basic training: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result .

 So my question is: How do you implement a call to choose a location and create a txt-file and the take said filelocation to fill it with text, with the registerForActivityResult without moving to another Activity/with staying on the Activity you are.

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.Export -> {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)

            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            intent.type = "text/plain"
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Spells.txt")

            startActivityForResult(intent, 112)
            return true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, resultData: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData)
    if (requestCode == 112 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        val path = resultData?.data?.path
        val myfile: File
        if (path != null) {
            myfile = File(path)
            ....
            doing stuff()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the Problem in my thinking. I just had to use the Intent I created before to launch the resultLauncher, that was shown on the previous question, instead of the Activity-changing Intent.

Also, I found, that the Value val resultLauncher, that was shown, had to be declared inside the class but outside the other functions, which was the part, where I got confused. Guess I got routine-blinded and should take more Breaks

Comment: I've the same problem and i get the error 'LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED'. 
Can you post your solution please.

Answer (score 1):

Here some code about how you can use the new  registerForActivityResult approach, in this case It replaces the Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent.

```
 class YourActivity {
       // This is the launcher ...
       // CreateDocument() -> Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT
  
       private val getCreateFileUriContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument()) { uri: Uri? ->
            // Handle the returned Uri
            uri?.let { onCreateFileSelected(it) }
            
            
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)        
            //....
            
             someButton.setOnClickListener {
                //launch for results
                getCreateFileUriContent.launch("test.json")
            }
      }     
            
    }
```