# Refresh Activity

Tags: java, android

This is my scenario

- Activity A (List of user)
- Activity B (User Add Activity)

Desired Flow in app

Step 1: A ==> B

Step 2: B ==> A

Step 3 (Required flow):

**Activity A** has to reload itself or call **loadListView()** function after **Activity B** exits or is closed.

```
onCreate(){
.......
....
        btnAddClient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent( ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        loadListView();
......
....
}
```

Comment: it's difficult to say what the problem is, since you didn't say you had a problem. What you call "reload itself" is very generic. An activity that is stopped will eventually be destroyed and then recreated when you return so if you're calling `loadListView` from `onCreate` chances are it's being called. If not, you can move that to `onStart` but the truth is, this is all a "hack". You need to revisit your architecture. The activity shouldn't care whether it's being loaded or "reloaded". It should receive the data in the correct state and should not drive it.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Thanks and yes I was also looking for best practices regarding this app flow. Can you please suggest me some architecture related tutorials or links that you find helpful?

Comment: Well, you have [the official developer page](https://developer.android.com/), from there you have a few choices, [the developer guides](https://developer.android.com/guide) are probably a good starting point. After understanding [Android Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals), I think taking a look at this specific architecture stuff should be done through [the Jetpack/Architecture documentation and samples](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture)

Answer (score 2):

Try to call `loadListView()` in `onStart` or `onResume` methods. It will refresh the list when you come back to your activity

Comment: Great!! this also worked for me but is this a good practice?

Comment: Good practice to have some actual state of the app and subscribe for updates from this state.
How you can implement it:

Use a database.
On the activity B you should store new item to the database.
on the Activity A you should subscribe for updates from database in onCreate method. In this way you should not check changes in your list and reload list every time where activity re-started. Because updates will be received immediately. There are some mechanism that allows to subscribe for updates like LiveData or RxJava. Room database supports both approaches.

Comment: Here you can find a detailed tutorial - how create small application using Room database library and LiveData:
https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-6-working-with-architecture-components/lesson-14-room,-livedata,-viewmodel/14-1-a-room-livedata-viewmodel/14-1-a-room-livedata-viewmodel.html

  LiveData overview:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Room overview:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Answer (score 1):

Getting a result from an activity

From your Activity A, call the Activity B using the startActivityForResult() method.

```
int RESULT_CODE = 123;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CODE);
```

Now in your ActivityA class, write the following code for the onActivityResult() method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            bool status=data.getBooleanExtra("isUserAdded");
            if(status)
            {
             loadListView();
            }
        }
    }
} //onActivityResult
```

Return back to ActivityA with status.

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("isUserAdded",true);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: Great!! this worked for me but  I found onActivityResult is deprecated. So for those who would like to update please refere https://stackoverflow.com/a/63654043/4370398