# onActivityResult deprecated, how to handle google signin in fragment for android(Java)?

Tags: android, google-signin, google-fit

```
    @Override **//depricated**
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE) {
                insertAndVerifySession();
            }
        }
    }

GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                fragment,
                REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE,
                GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context),
                fitnessOptions);
```

What's the alternative of onActivityResult for GoogleSignIn in Fragment?

Comment: there is a new approach, get familiar with [`ActivityResultContracts`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts) class from AndroidX. [HERE](https://medium.com/quinbay/activityresultcontract-activityresultapis-in-androidx-935bf1fc9ed2) you have some explanations and tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we are familiar with this approach, but my concern is how we can use it with GoogleSignIn? `GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                fragment,
                REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE,
                GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context),
                fitnessOptions);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Comment: Did you get your answer @user16388371 ? I am looking answer for the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) said, you can get sign in intent by calling `getSignInIntent`

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> exampleActivityResult= registerForActivityResult(
new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.getData());
handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }
});



//call
   exampleActivityResult.launch(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent());
```

**Update - 30-11-2021**

here is the [new method by google](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started) !

Comment: How about using `GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions()` with the new API?

Comment: @Max did you find a solution for this? Thanks

Comment: @MirianaItani I just used the old way, with `onActivityResult`. It's deprecated but it's not going away for the next couple of years. And by the time it does get removed, Google will probably come up with a solution for this.

Comment: How use it in fragments?

Comment: Goddam it Google sort your s*** out

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to register ActivityResultContracts, i used similar code in my project:

```
 //declare ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> 
 ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> ResultLauncher;
```

inside onAttach or onCreate do the assignment

```
ResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                 ...//do stuff on result here
                      /* 
                  There are no request codes
                              You can put request code in extra and Unpack it as your string/int e.t.c
                      Intent data = result.getData();
                       assert data != null;
                        String req_code = data.getStringExtra("reqCode");
                             if(req_code.equal(REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE){
                                     ...do stuff
                                           }
                         */
                    }
                });
```

to launch activity just use .launch (intent)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SomeClass.class);
 ResultLauncher.launch(intent);
```

Also you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative) for similar question and how to handle it in Kotlin/Java
Hopes it helps

Comment: This doesn't explain how to request permissions from GoogleSignIn with the new API. Where would I get the Intent from?

Comment: @Max You can build the intent with signed in account's info. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75711587/1135631

Answer (score 0):

After on activity result is deprecated we use someActivityResultLauncher.launch

In Java:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
 someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
```

In Kotlin:

```
val intent = Intent(this, Example::class.java)
resultLauncher.launch(intent)
```

For fetching results we use registerForActivityResult

In Java:

```
 ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> exampleActivityResult= registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    // There are no request codes in this method 
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                }
            }
        });
```

In Kotlin:

```
var exampleActivityResult= registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    // There are no request codes in this method 
    val data: Intent? = result.data
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we know this approach, the main concern is how we can use google signing infragment?  `GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(                 fragment,                 REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE,                 GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context),                 fitnessOptions); `

Comment: How use it in fragments?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be replacement for the deprecated onActivityResult, but to use the new contracts. Here's a neat snippet to handle sign in to google in a contained class.

https://gist.github.com/wintren/b866232ca01cfbfb4592fe909b989efd

After importing the `GoogleSignInActivityContract.kt` class the Activity code would be:

```
    // Before onCreate
    private val googleSignInRequest = registerForActivityResult(
        GoogleSignInActivityContract(),
        ::onGoogleSignInResult
    )

    private val googleSignInOptions: GoogleSignInOptions
        get() = 
            GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.GooglePlayServiceKey_WebClient))
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .build()

    fun triggerFunction {
        googleSignInRequest.launch(googleSignInOptions)
    }
```

There's more inte the snippet for handling the result.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for a solution to request permission in a fragment:

`private lateinit var googleAuthActivityResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>`

```
private val fitnessOptions: FitnessOptions by lazy {
    FitnessOptions.builder()
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
        .build()
}
```

onAttach:

```
googleAuthActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
        task.addOnCompleteListener {
            if (task.isSuccessful) handleRequest()
        }
    }
```

where you want to launch the intent:

```
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .addExtension(fitnessOptions)
            .build()
        val googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(requireContext(), gso)
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent

        googleAuthActivityResultLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
```

and do not forget onDestroyView:

```
googleAuthActivityResultLauncher.unregister()
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking to use `requestPermission` function with the new activity launcher way, here is a solution..

`GoogleSignIn.requestPermission()` internally calls `startActivityForResult` with an intent containing signed-in account's info.

So, what you can do is, **create an intent with the signed-in account info** and call the activity result launcher with that intent.
This will request the scope from the user.

**Intent for the scope you need**

```
fun getIntentForFitnessScope(context: Context): Intent {
        val signedInAccount: GoogleSignInAccount? = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context)
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.write"))
                .setAccountName(signedInAccount?.email!!)
                .build()
            return GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, gso).signInIntent
    }
```

**Activity result launcher**

```
val googleSignInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Do something with result.data()
        }
    }
```

**Launch the activity result launcher**

```
googleSignInLauncher.launch(getIntentForFitnessScope(context))
```