# How can I implement Firebase Google Sign in inside a DialogFragment? Overrides deprecated method in 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment'

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

```
public class LoginFrag extends DialogFragment {
final int RC_SIGN_IN = 977;
String TAG = "LoginFragLog";
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
Context mContext;
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
public LoginFrag() {
    // Empty constructor is required for DialogFragment
    // Make sure not to add arguments to the constructor
    // Use `newInstance` instead as shown below
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_frag, container);
    if(getDialog() != null){
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull @NotNull View view, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(mContext, gso);
}
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

startActivityForResult is crossed and it shows:
Call Activity.startActivityForResult(Intent, int) from the fragment's containing Activity.

**Deprecated:**

use registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContract, ActivityResultCallback) passing in a androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult object for the ActivityResultContract.

**Params:**

intent – The intent to start.
requestCode – The request code to be returned in onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) when the activity exits. Must be between 0 and 65535 to be considered valid. If given requestCode is greater than 65535, an IllegalArgumentException would be thrown

Similarly, for onActivityResult, it is also crossed out and it shows: Overrides deprecated method in 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment'

What I am trying to accomplish is: I have Main activity with bottom navigation with fragments and inside one fragment i have a Dialog Fragment which code is this one i.e, LoginFrag. is it because dialog fragment cannot receive call back from login activity of google i.e, onActivityResult. how can i solve this problem, please help. I just want to login from this Dialog Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
        }
    }
}
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener((Executor) this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
@Override
public void onAttach(@NotNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext = context;
}
```

}

Below is the parent Fragment of LoginFrag:

```
public class DiscussionFragment extends Fragment {
FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser user;
public DiscussionFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

private void showLogin() {
    FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = getActivity();
    FragmentManager fm;
    assert fragmentActivity != null;
    fm = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    LoginFrag loginFrag = new LoginFrag();
    loginFrag.setCancelable(false);
    loginFrag.show(fm,"login_frag");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.discussion_layout, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(user == null){
        showLogin();
    }
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#register)? It tells you exactly how to use the `registerForActivityResult`+`launch` APIs, which you can absolutely use from a DialogFragment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68265331/3505444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your logic:

- Move Google sign operations to MainActivity
- Create event listener interface in Fragment and pass to activity
- Set event listener in Activity when initialize fragment

  ```
        private LoginListener loginListener;

        public interface LoginListener {
          public void onLoginClick();
        }

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            loginListener.onLoginClick();
          }
        });

        private void setLoginListener(LoginListener loginListener){
          this.loginListener = loginListener;
        }

        public static class MainActivity extends Activity
          implements YourFragment.LoginListener{
          ...
        YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
        fragment.setLoginListener(this);

        @Override
        public void onLoginClick() {
            // start google sign
        }
  ```