# onactivityresult() is deprecated in android fragment

Tags: java, android, deprecated

I search on google for onactivityresult() is deprecated. but my problem was not solve . here is the code of fragment

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull @NotNull String[] permissions, @NonNull @NotNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode){
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if (grantResults.length >0 ){
                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean writeStorageAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (cameraAccepted && writeStorageAccepted){
                        pickFromCamera();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enable camera & storage permission first ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

            }
   private void pickFromCamera() {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,"Temp Pic");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Temp Description");
        // put image uri
        image_uri = requireActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        // intent tom start camera
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);

    }

    private void pickFromGallery() {
        // pick from gallery
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent .ACTION_PICK);
        galleryIntent.setType("Images/*");
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE);
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative This is exacly what you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin** - Below code instead of *`startActivityForResult`* deprecation
this method gives the result itself and returns a value.

```
val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    when (result.resultCode) {
        Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
            // logic
        }
        else -> {
            // logic
        }
    }
}
```