# How to use registerForActivityResult correctly? Getting "LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-jetpack, startactivityforresult

I use `registerForActivityResult` just like :

```
package com.example.livedata

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Settings
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.livedata.databinding.ActivityAddBinding
import com.example.livedata.databinding.DialogCustomImageSelectionBinding


class AddActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAddBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityAddBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setupActionBar()

        binding.photoAdd.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    private fun setupActionBar() {
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { onBackPressed() }
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        if (v != null) {
            when (v.id) {
                R.id.photo_add -> {
                    imageDialog()
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun imageDialog() {
        val dialog = Dialog(this)
        val dialogBinding: DialogCustomImageSelectionBinding =
            DialogCustomImageSelectionBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        dialog.setContentView(dialogBinding.root)
        dialog.show()

        dialogBinding.impCamera.setOnClickListener {
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview()) {
                if (it != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@AddActivity, "TakePicturePreview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }.launch(null).apply { arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA) }
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            data?.let {
                val bp = data.getParcelableExtra<Bitmap>("data")
                binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(bp)

            }
        }
    }

    private fun showPermissions() {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Applay Permissions!")
            .setPositiveButton("Go to Settings") { _, _ ->
                try {
                    val intel = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
                    val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
                    intel.data = uri
                    startActivity(intel)
                } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }.show()
    }
}
```

But it do not work and throw an exception here :

```
2021-07-16 15:38:50.472 29885-29885/com.example.livedata E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.livedata, PID: 29885
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner com.example.livedata.AddActivity@9fc53b9 is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.register(ActivityResultRegistry.java:123)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.registerForActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:659)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.registerForActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:668)
        at com.example.livedata.AddActivity.imageDialog$lambda-3(AddActivity.kt:68)
        at com.example.livedata.AddActivity.lambda$N7K_EbTML-ycmUwpA7-i8b_L-Sw(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.livedata.-$$Lambda$AddActivity$N7K_EbTML-ycmUwpA7-i8b_L-Sw.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7281)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7255)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:828)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27925)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8393)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
2021-07-16 15:38:50.539 1689-2062/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'ba7a009 com.example.livedata/com.example.livedata.AddActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

How can I use the registerForActivityResult to accomplish this task instead of the deprecated method? All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace startActivityForResult with Activity Result APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455381/how-to-replace-startactivityforresult-with-activity-result-apis)

Comment: Hey try this hope it matches your question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68268567/onactivityresult-is-deprecated-in-android-fragment/68269483#68269483

Comment: I don't think those duplicates are quite on point - they don't describe how to avoid the error.  I've tried to address that in my answer.

Answer (score 12):

You're trying to call `registerForActivityResult` in a click listener.  That's not going to work, because your `Activity` might be destroyed and recreated before the result is delivered.  The recreated `Activity` won't have been registered to receive the result, because it only registers when you click the button, and the button was only clicked in the *original* `Activity`.

To fix this, you need to call `registerForActivityResult` unconditionally and store the result in a variable:

```kotlin
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val activityLauncher = registerForActivityResult(...
```

That way, the recreated `Activity` *will* be registered to receive the result.  Then use that `activityLauncher` variable to launch it from the button click listener.

For more information, see the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Comment: What about "unregister()", will that happen automatically if "registerForActivityResult(...)" is used?

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin - Below code instead of `startActivityForResult` deprecation this method gives the result itself and returns a value.

```
val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    when (result.resultCode) {
        Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
            // logic
        }
        else -> {
            // logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put this code on my frament?

Comment: like variable, you should declare this and use this variable where you want with resultLauncher.launch(Intent(your intent))

Comment: I tried this for another problem, and it did not work. Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75644844/how-to-lauch-whatsapp-contact-list

Comment: I saw the above question, there is an issue in the what's app intent package.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Java Code version - Using ActivityResultLauncher

- `In Activity A : Launch Activity B, eg: if you using a Button View onSetClickListener`

Button `btn` = findViewById(`enter button view id name here`)

- Call the btn.setOnClickListener and place this code in the onClick()-method of the button

  `mStartForResult.launch(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class));`
- Call ActivityResultLauncher API and retrieve the result from Activity B using the Intent & the ResultCode.

`

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>()

{ 
 
if(result.getResultCode()== Activity.RESULT_OK) 

{
   

            
           Intent intent = result.getData();
        
            'enter your code here'


}
});
```

- You may want to use ***shared preferences*** to save and retrieve data from ActivityB to A
- In Activity B: Call the btn.setOnClickListener and place this code in the onClick()-method of the button:

  ```
      `Intent intent = new  Intent(DestinationActivity.this,MainActivity.class);`
   intent.putExtra(EXTRA, `enter your input(int or String) here`);
   setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
   finish();
  ```