# OnActivityResult isn't being called

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm calling startActivityForResult and the other Activity starts correctly, but the method onActivityResult isn't being called, it just calls OnCreate

This is the code where I call startActivityForResult

```
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

And this is the method onActivityResult on the MainActivity that isn't being called. This is the code

```
 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        System.out.println("ewe")
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
        if (requestCode == 2) {
            //do the things u wanted
            val repetitionTime = 10L;
            alarm = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, Pedometer::class.java)
            val pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, 0, intent, 0)

            val alarmInfo =  AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pi);

            alarm!!.setAlarmClock(alarmInfo, pi);
        }
    }
```

I have debugged the code and the method is not called at all.

I tried looking for answers and tried:

-I'm calling startActivityForResult correctly and with a positive number.

-There isn't android:launchMode="singleInstance" on my manifest. Here's my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.walker">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Walker">
        <activity android:name=".Pedometer"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="TaskPlanner" android:exported="true">  </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried looking on the internet for more answers and tried looking in the documentation but couldn't find anything. Any help super appreciated, thanks in advance to anyone who answers!

SOLUTION

Looks like I just wasn't understanding how startActivityForResult. It turns out that startActivityForResult starts an activity and then after the new started activity finishes the onActivityResultMethod is called. I was trying to create a new activity and pass an argument using it right on the creation, so of course it didn't work.

To pass an argument to a new activity I just used:

```
 val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java);
        intent.putExtra("result",2);
        setResult(2,intent);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();//finishing activity
```

And then to retrieve the value

```
  val extras = intent.extras
        if (extras != null) {
            val value = extras.getString("result")
            extras.putString("result", null);
}
```

Comment: Post the other activity's code, where it sets the result. (and calls `finish()`)

Comment: Looks like I just wasn't understanding how startActivityForResult. It turns out that startActivityForResult starts an activity and then after the new started activity finishes the onActivityResultMethod is called. I was trying to create a new activity and pass an argument using it right on the creation, so of course it didn't work.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: onActivityResult is deprecated use the latest one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68405703/how-to-use-registerforactivityresult-correctly-getting-lifecycleowners-must-ca/68408495#68408495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just wasn't understanding how startActivityForResult. It turns out that startActivityForResult starts an activity and then after the new started activity finishes the onActivityResultMethod is called. I was trying to create a new activity and pass an argument using it right on the creation, so of course it didn't work.

To pass an argument to a new activity I just used:

```
 val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java);
        intent.putExtra("result",2);
        setResult(2,intent);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();//finishing activity
```

And then to retrieve the value

```
  val extras = intent.extras
        if (extras != null) {
            val value = extras.getString("result")
            extras.putString("result", null);
}
```