# Look this "startActivityForResult()" codes, this function was deprecated. How to change this codes in Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, startactivityforresult

Look this startActivityForResult() codes, this function was deprecated.
How to change this codes in Fragment?

What's mean "Call Activity.startActivityForResult(Intent, int) from the fragment's containing Activity."??

Please, simply guide to me...

```kotlin
private const val REQUEST_PHOTO = 2

class ExampleFragment:Fragment(), DatePickerFragment.Callbacks {

    private lateinit var photoUri : Uri

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        ...

        photoButton.apply {
            val packageManager : PackageManager = requireActivity().packageManager

                val captureImage = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            val resolvedActivity : ResolveInfo? =
                packageManager.resolveActivity(captureImage,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)

            if (resolvedActivity == null) {
                isEnabled = false
            }

            setOnClickListener {
                captureImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri)

                val cameraActivities : List<ResolveInfo> =
                    packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureImage, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)

                for (cameraActivity in cameraActivities) {
                    requireActivity().grantUriPermission(
                        cameraActivity.activityInfo.packageName,photoUri,
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                    )
                }
                startActivityForResult(captureImage, REQUEST_PHOTO)  // <<<< Deprecated 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a variable of type `ActivityResultLauncher` called `captureImageLauncher`

You have to register a result callback: (which is the alternative of the previously used `onActivityResult` method) like this. So you can move all your code which was under `onActivityResult` here in this callback

```kotlin
private val captureImageLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        result: ActivityResult ->
        
        // Here You handle the result that the activity sent back
        // You can use methods like result.resultCode or result.data to retrieve information
    }
```

This will create an `ActivityResultLauncher` that You will use later instead of `startActivityForResult` like this:(instead of the `startActivityForResult` method. You also won't be needing an explicit request code because it makes thing unnecessarily complicated)

```kotlin
captureImageLauncher.launch(captureImage) // captureImage is the intent that You've created
```

More information [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).