# onActivityResult is deprecated in DialogFragments but not in Activity

Tags: android, deprecated

in activity this method still work but when i call it in Dialog Fragments, it is deprecated.

in DialogFragment
[image]

in Activity
[image]

Edit:i use the Matisse library for load image , it like

library link: https://github.com/zhihu/Matisse

```
 Matisse.from(getActivity())
                        .choose(MimeType.ofImage())
                        .countable(true)
                        .maxSelectable(9)
                        .addFilter(new GifSizeFilter(320, 320, 5 * Filter.K * Filter.K))
                        .restrictOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED)
                        .thumbnailScale(0.85f)
                        .imageEngine(new GlideEngine())
                        .showPreview(false) // Default is `true`
                        .forResult(REQUEST_CODE_AVATAR);
```

how can i use ActivityResultLaucher for this library?

explain to me why and how can i fix it? please

**Have a nice day,everyone!**

Comment: is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative the solution?

Comment: thanks you but i just edit my question, can you help me in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that result activity is deprecated. This is the new way to obtain results from an activity. You should be able to do similarly with a dialog fragment. The reason it was deprecated is because when there is low memory inactive activities are often removed along with the result and this causes errors.

```
// You can do the assignment inside onAttach or onCreate, i.e, before the activity is displayed
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // There are no request codes
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        doSomeOperations();
                    }
                }
            });

    public void openSomeActivityForResult() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }
```

Comment: i just edit my question, can you help me in this case, thanks so much!