# Open simple text file by open file dialog in Jetpack Compose and read line by line

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack

I would like to open a simple text file and read this line by line:

I triggered the Open File Dialog [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68778770):

```
val result = remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument()) {
    result.value = it
}

Button(onClick = { launcher.launch(arrayOf("text/plain")) }) {
    Text(text = "Open Document")
}

Loadfile(result.value)
```

whereas `result.value` is of type `Uri` and I try to open file:

```
@Composable
fun Loadfile(uri: Uri?) {

    Log.d("Loadfile", "Load ${uri.toString()}")

    if(uri==null) {
        Log.e("Loadfile", "File could not load!")    
    } else {
        val file = File(uri.path)
        try {
            BufferedReader(FileReader(file)).use { br ->
                Log.d("Loadfile", "Total Lines: ${br.lines()}")
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately IOException catches a
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/document:1000014685: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

The text file is named lola.txt in internal Android `Documents` folder; I don't know where 1000014685 comes from!?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using .path like that will not work, I don't remember exact solution. But it should be about reading uri content as stream

Answer (score 0):

It's rarely appropriate to open a `URI` or `URL` using methods meant for files. You should instead open an `InputStream` directly, using the `URL.openStream()` method:

```
@Composable
fun Loadfile(uri: Uri?) {
    Log.d("Loadfile", "Loading $uri")

    if (uri == null) {
        Log.e("Loadfile", "File could not be loaded.")    
    } else {
        try {
            uri.toURL().openStream().bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
                Log.d("Loadfile", "Total Lines: ${lines.count()}")
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            log.e("Loadfile", "Exception trying to load $uri", e)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using the `contentResolver`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LoadFileFromUri(uri: Uri?) {
    val contentResolver = LocalContext.current.contentResolver

    if(uri==null) {
        Log.e("LoadFileFromUri", "Unable to load the file")    
    } else {
        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
        var line = reader.readLine()

        while (line != null) {
            Log.d("LoadFileFromUri", line)
            line = reader.readLine()
        }
    }
}
```