# ActivityResultLauncher pass custom requestcode

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I've got a simple ActivityResultLauncher implementation, where I can select an image from the gallery:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> actResLauncher;
actResLauncher = registerForActivityResult(   new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),this);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
actResLauncher.launch(intent);
```

And the result:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult  result) {
    if(result.getResultCode()== Activity.RESULT_OK){

    }
}
```

The issue is with this code is that I rely on the predefined Resultcodes like Activity.RESULT_OK or Activity.RESULT_CANCELED. Is there a way to pass custom Requestcodes when launching the intent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you do not need `onActivityResult()`. That way was old. You now have launchers for specific purposes. So no more request codes
You now do it like below.
Create a function like this:

```java
ActivityResultLauncher<String> imageActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
            uri -> 
               //do something with uri
            });
```

And then wherever you want to launch this, just write:

```java
imageActivityResultLauncher.launch("image/*");
```

For more details refer to this stackoverflow answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63654043/12555686

Comment: How would i handle cancel events in that way or lets say in otjer words, how do you from which intent u receive the uri? with custom result code(s) u would now the result origin, or am i missing something?

Comment: This lets you have a activity result for everytime you launch

Comment: So its specific. If you had another launcher you'll create another launcher function like this. This one is specific to one launch i.e. image one

Comment: You'll have a launcher function specific for that one launch so no more request codes. If you want to startactivityresult for another thing, create another function like that

Comment: I have also made edits to my answer. Please refer that link

Comment: so the answer is that it's not possible to pass request codes, as i need to create an own listener for each intent i want to launch? :/

Comment: In this approach how should I pass the IP address I want the file be uploaded to and is specific for each file??