# What is alternative startActivityFoResultr??? For sending data one Activity to another Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, startactivityforresult

I have a issue, ActivityForResult is deprecated, what is alternative to send data one to another activity?? I have heard about ActivityResultLauncher Btw how can i send data with ActivityResultLauncher?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Comment: No this is not answer of my question.. i did try btw it was not help me.