# take data from child activity to main activity in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

Hi all I'm new to **android development(I'm using Kotlin) and startActivityForResult is deprecated** trying to make one simple app
To make it simple :

I have a main activity with two button first activity and second activity.

I have a "child" activity with a text fields and a finish button.

When I click the main activity button, the child activity opens (it works data can also be access which i pass from main activity). Then I put some text to the text fields and when I click the finish button I want the data from the text fields to be transferred to the main activity, and I can't get this working. followed medium, yt and stackoverflow not able to make it work

my main activity code

```
   package com.example.data

 import android.app.Activity
import android.app.Instrumentation
import android.content.Intent
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
  import android.os.Bundle
 import android.preference.PreferenceManager
 import android.widget.Button
  import android.widget.EditText
  import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
 import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts

  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
companion object{
  private const val FIRST_ACTIVITY_RESULT = 1
}
lateinit var activityResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val firstbtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.first_activity_btn)
    val first_text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.first_activity_text)
    val secondbtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.second_activity_btn)
    val edit = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_name)


     firstbtn.setOnClickListener{
        var intent = Intent(this,first_activity::class.java)
      intent.putExtra("data_name",edit.text.toString())
        activityResultLauncher.launch(intent)

        finish()
    }

    secondbtn.setOnClickListener{
        var intent = Intent(this,second_activity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

    activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result:ActivityResult?->
        if (result!!.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(result.data!!.extras!!.getString("data_transfer").toString() == "yes"){

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "user send reply", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "sorry user did not send reply", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

  }
       }
```

first activity code

```
   package com.example.data

  import android.app.Activity
  import android.content.Intent
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.widget.Button
  import android.widget.EditText
  import android.widget.TextView

    class first_activity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first)
    val finish = findViewById<Button>(R.id.finish_btn)
    val textData = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_first_activity)
    val edit = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_text_first_activity)

    textData.text = intent.extras!!.getString("data_name")

    finish.setOnClickListener{
  //            val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
    //            intent.putExtra("success","success message woohooo!!!")
      //            startActivity(intent)
        val intent = Intent()
   //            val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("data_transfer",edit.text.toString())
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent)
    //            startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}
     }
```

Comment: Have you tried this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative This might solve your problem.

Comment: yes, but not able to get desired result as i mention in the Question @DouglasCunha

Answer (score 1):

what you need is **registerForActivityResult()**
here is a sample project and you can read more about this new API

use-case : user by typing in input(Second Activity) and click button can recive input text in MainActivity(first activity):

MainActivity class:

```
    import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var txt:TextView
    lateinit var btn:Button
    private val secondActivityWithResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
        { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                result.data?.getStringExtra("name")?.let { txt.text = it }
            }
        }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btn = findViewById(R.id.next_activity)
        txt = findViewById(R.id.returned_text)
        btn.setOnClickListener{
            secondActivityWithResult.launch(Intent(this,SecondActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_activity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/returned_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="your string appear here"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

SecondActivity class:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText


class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var input:EditText
    lateinit var btn:Button
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)
        btn = findViewById(R.id.return_btn)
        input = findViewById(R.id.my_input)

        btn.setOnClickListener{
            SharedValues.myString = input.text.toString()
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.putExtra("name","my love is NAHID MORADI")
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent)
            finish()
     
        }
    }
}
```

activity_second XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/my_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="type here"

        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/return_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:text="Return To FirstActivity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_input" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thank you @soheil but not able to get the desired result text is not change when i move from 2nd activity to main activity where as when i log the value of `sharedValue.myString` it is updating accordingly but not show on mainactivity

Comment: as i said this is simple way and work just one time, for better usage you must optimize it, this is just an idea,but this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative is the best way that work in place of tartActivityForResult

Comment: i edit by better solution registerForActivityResult() and whit complete code for you inform me if it is ok for you

Comment: i'm able to to find out another solution for my problem that is why a bit late reply on this problem but this one also work... @soheil

Comment: i suggest you always this way,be happy