# wait activity for result from another app android

Tags: android, android-activity, share, startactivityforresult

I have 2 applications, APP1 will start a transaction and will send some data to APP2 then APP2 will return to APP1 with updated data then APP1 will continue the transaction.

what is the best way to this in android?

is there a way to wait activity for result from another app?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Answer (score 0):

I used to use startActivityForResult for same situation like you.
but I see it is deprecated now and I recommend you to check this.

[OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Comment: will it work between different apps? i tried to use it but i the intent that returned from app2 to app1 with null