# how to solve this startActivityForResult

Tags: android-studio

[how to solve this kind of problem starActivityForResult please any budy guide me to solve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owdEI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startActivityForResult` is deprecated following is new the way. [Here](https://github.com/orbitalsonic/ActivityForResult-Latest-Android-Kotlin) is a full source code example

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var tvResult:TextView
    private lateinit var btnNext:Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        tvResult = findViewById(R.id.tv_result)
        btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btn_next)

        btnNext.setOnClickListener {
            openActivityForResult(Intent(this,SampleActivity::class.java))
        }

    }

    private var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val mIntent: Intent? = result.data
            val mDataString = mIntent?.getStringExtra("result_data")
            tvResult.text = mDataString

        }
    }

    private fun openActivityForResult(mIntent: Intent) {
        resultLauncher.launch(mIntent)
    }
}
```

**SampleActivity**

```
class SampleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var btnDone: Button
    private val sampleData = "Sample Activity Result Data"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample)

        btnDone = findViewById(R.id.btn_done)
        btnDone.setOnClickListener{
            returnForResult()
        }
    }

    private fun returnForResult(){
        val replyIntent = Intent()
        replyIntent.putExtra(
            "result_data",
            sampleData
        )
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, replyIntent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`startActivityForResult` is deprecated, meaning that it will no longer be supported going forward. That is why Android Studio is showing you the lines through the code. Instead, review this Stackoverflow post on alternative options:
[OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)