# Kotlin - Sending data from activity back to fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

When a user presses `btnOpen` in the FirstFragment, it'll create an activity. When clicks `btnDone` in SecondActivity, it should close the activity and pass back a `String` to the fragment.

FirstFragment.kt

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    btnOpen.setOnClickListener {
    var someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        StartActivityForResult(),
        ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> { result ->
            println(result.data)
        })

    val intent = Intent(context, SecondActivity::class.java)
    activityLauncher.launch(intent)
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    btnDone.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this@InputAmountActivity,FirstFragment::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Total","some data")
        finish()
    }
}
```

I'm getting null when attempting to print `result.data`. How exactly do I get the value of `total` from SecondActivity?

Comment: You can use activity result launcher. This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/68540221/10248593 and https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: I had a long and hard look at that question you suggested this morning. It was as confusing as the documentation to me, but thanks, I think I got it now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you are creating an `Intent` and then just throwing it away without doing anything with it. You need to use [`setResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent)) to actually send it back to your first activity:

```
btnDone.setOnClickListener{
    val intent = Intent(this@InputAmountActivity,FirstFragment::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("Total","some data")
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
    finish()
}
```