# Deprecated use of startActivityForResult (KOTLIN) (RESOLVED)

Tags: android, image, android-studio, kotlin, deprecated

First of all, this's the UPDATED project : https://github.com/DoomedyDoomed/ShareSomePics

**EDIT**

This code was an old use of activityForResult().
I have shared my resolved code down below. Simply it works for opennig gallery , selecting an image and store it with Bitmap to upload it to database. I got help from this [post here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

**This is the part of that post helped me:**

```
fun openSomeActivityForResult() {
    val intent = Intent(this, SomeActivity::class.java)
    resultLauncher.launch(intent)
}

var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // There are no request codes
        val data: Intent? = result.data
        doSomeOperations()
    }
}
```

**This is the old way of use.**

```
class SharePhotograph : AppCompatActivity() {

private var pickedImage : Uri? = null
private var pickedBitmap : Bitmap? = null
private lateinit var storage : FirebaseStorage
private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var database : FirebaseFirestore

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_share_photograph)

    val imageSelect = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
    val butShare = findViewById<Button>(R.id.butShare)
    val userCommentText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.userCommentText)

    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    imageSelect.setOnClickListener{
        pickImage()
    }

    butShare.setOnClickListener{
        //Storage Process
        //UUID -> Universal Unique ID
        val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
        val imageName = "${uuid}.jpg"

        val reference = storage.reference
        val imageReference = reference.child("images").child(imageName)

        if  (pickedImage != null){
            imageReference.putFile(pickedImage!!).addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                val uploadedImageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images").child(imageName)
                uploadedImageReference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                    val downloadUrl = uri.toString()
                    val currentUserEmail = auth.currentUser!!.email.toString()
                    val userComment = userCommentText.text.toString()
                    val date = Timestamp.now()

                    //Database Process
                    val postHashMap = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
                    postHashMap["Image URL"] = downloadUrl
                    postHashMap["User Email"] = currentUserEmail
                    postHashMap["User Comment"] = userComment
                    postHashMap["Post Date"] = date

                    database.collection("Post").add(postHashMap).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if(task.isSuccessful){
                            Toast.makeText(this,"Uploaded!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            finish()
                        }
                    }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,exception.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,exception.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun pickImage(){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //No Permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),1)
    }else {
        //If Already Had Permission
        val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,2)
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
)   {
    if (requestCode == 1){
        if(grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,2)
        }
    }

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}
@Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){

        pickedImage = data.data

        if (pickedImage != null){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28)
            {
                val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver,pickedImage!!)
                pickedBitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                val imageSelect = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
                imageSelect.setImageBitmap(pickedBitmap)
            }
            else
            {
                pickedBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver,pickedImage)
                val imageSelect = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
                imageSelect.setImageBitmap(pickedBitmap)
            }
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

}

Comment: Picking an image is [the exact example the documentation uses](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch). Is there a reason you aren't following the documentation? You don't need any runtime permissions for getting an image either - that code is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Comment: @RohitJakhar It s more like confusing me in a way. As you guys trying to help me i m still working to trying to work it out.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I checked the documentation. I am a beginner and had trouble with using those new use of codes. I understood the codes. But like i said i wasn t able to alter the code for my benefits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the code finally. Thanks for everyone trying to help. I am sure that a lot of people like me (beginner) are learning from old videos and will have this problem. I hope this helps!

Compare both codes and use it for your way.

```
class SharePhotograph : AppCompatActivity() {

private var pickedImage : Uri? = null
private var pickedBitmap : Bitmap? = null
private lateinit var storage : FirebaseStorage
private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var database : FirebaseFirestore

private var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // There are no request codes
        val data: Intent? = result.data
        pickedImage = data?.data

        if (pickedImage != null){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28)
            {
                val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver,pickedImage!!)
                pickedBitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                val imageSelect = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
                imageSelect.setImageBitmap(pickedBitmap)
            }
            else
            {
                pickedBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver,pickedImage)
                val imageSelect = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
                imageSelect.setImageBitmap(pickedBitmap)
            }
        }
    }
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_share_photograph)

    val imageSelect = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
    val butShare = findViewById<Button>(R.id.butShare)
    val userCommentText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.userCommentText)

    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        imageSelect.setOnClickListener{
        pickImage()
    }

    butShare.setOnClickListener{
        //Storage Process
        //UUID -> Universal Unique ID
        val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
        val imageName = "${uuid}.jpg"

        val reference = storage.reference
        val imageReference = reference.child("images").child(imageName)

        if  (pickedImage != null){
            imageReference.putFile(pickedImage!!).addOnSuccessListener {
                val uploadedImageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images").child(imageName)
                uploadedImageReference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                    val downloadUrl = uri.toString()
                    val currentUserEmail = auth.currentUser!!.email.toString()
                    val userComment = userCommentText.text.toString()
                    val date = Timestamp.now()

                    //Database Process
                    val postHashMap = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
                    postHashMap["Image URL"] = downloadUrl
                    postHashMap["User Email"] = currentUserEmail
                    postHashMap["User Comment"] = userComment
                    postHashMap["Post Date"] = date

                    database.collection("Post").add(postHashMap).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if(task.isSuccessful){
                            Toast.makeText(this,"Uploaded!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            finish()
                        }
                    }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,exception.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,exception.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private fun pickImage(){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //No Permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),1)
    }else {
        openGallery()
    }
}
private fun openGallery() {
    val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    resultLauncher.launch(galleryIntent)
}
```

}