# How can I implement an architecturally clean sign-in screen in Jetpack compose?

Tags: firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, google-identity

My app uses Firebase authentication and I'm implementing a typical sign-in screen with buttons to sign in with Google, email etc. It's surprisingly difficult. I have a `LocalUser` class to hold the user's profile (name, email etc), state (whether they're logged in or in the process of logging in etc), and provide methods to start the process when a button is clicked. This seems like an ideal candidate for a `ViewModel`.

The trouble is, `ViewModel`s mustn't hold a reference to an `Activity`, but the Google Identity SDK needs such a reference as part of its mechanism for providing its result to my code. I can't think of a way to decouple the `ViewModel` that doesn't still leave the `ViewModel` referencing the `Activity`, albeit indirectly.

Is it OK to just remove the `ViewModel` inheritance from my `LocalUser` class and pass it directly to my sign in screen (and from there to each control that needs it)? Is it OK for a `Composable` to hold a reference to `Activity`?

Comment: Don't add the context or objects that hold context inside the ViewModel. If you want to use Firebase sign-in with Google using Jetpack Compose, please check [this](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) out. Here's also the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: I'm not using One-Tap, because I don't think it's necessary to have separate flows for sign-in and sign-up in my app. I used the [SignIn API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in-identity) instead. This relies on the [Activity Result API](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result). That doesn't seem to be the case in your app?

Comment: I've since discovered the existence of `rememberLauncherForActivityResult` which  might help in my case. I haven't got round to trying it yet though.

Comment: The [Activity Result API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in-identity) will be deprecated, check the note, "Google Identity Services will eventually replace the existing Google Sign-In API.". So sooner or later you'll have to change that,

Comment: I am already using GIS though. As it says on that page we both linked, GIS includes a new Sign-In API to replace the old one (in addition to providing the One Tap API), but it still uses Activity Result.

Comment: [OnActivityResult method is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative). So you should also consider implementing the new approach.

Comment: `onActivityResult` is deprecated, but I don't think [the Activity Result API](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) is. That's what replaces the deprecated method.

Comment: Indeed, registerForActivityResult is the new way of handling the result from an activity.