# How to change this piece of code from (startActivityForResult) to (ActivityResultLauncher) because startActivityForResult is deprecated?

Tags: java, android

I know there are some other ways to update RecyclerView like restarting the activity or putting update code inside `onResume();` but none of these two ways are efficient, any how. I've used  `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);` but now it is deprecated, I want to use `ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startForResult`. Here is the deprecated code which is working.

Inside MainActivity

```
fabNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddNote.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        }
    });
```

inside AddNote class:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();
```

Inside MainActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode== RESULT_OK){
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        allItems = dbHelper.getNotesAndChecklists();
        if(requestCode==1){
            if(data != null){
                noteAdapter.update(allItems);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to change this code to work with the method `ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>`?

I don't have anything to return and put it in `putExtra` , all I want is when the note added to SQLite Database and when RecyclerView gets updated when return back to main Activity. As I said I can use this way to update RecyclerView

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    noteAdapter.update(allItems);
}
```

but let's say the user pressed the home button and then return to the app at this time onResume gets called and RecyclerView is updated though it is unnecessary to update in this case because the data isn't changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enter the definition of your **ActivityResultLauncher** in the **onCreate()** method of your activity.

```
activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
                        allItems = dbHelper.getNotesAndChecklists();
                        
                        if(result.getData() != null)
                            noteAdapter.update(allItems);
                    }
                });
```

Also, add your ActivityResultLauncher variable as a **private attribute** of the activity.

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;
```

After that it starts the activity through it.

```
fabNote.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) view -> activityResultLauncher
                .launch(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddNote.class)));
```

Comment: @Feda Cana Awesome. It's working now. I voted up though I don't have enough reputation to vote  now.

Comment: Though one more question, is it a problem if I make ActivityResultLauncher public?

Comment: No, no problem but it would be a good idea to keep the activity variables private. I'm glad I could help you xD