# Firebase google sign in methods deprecated

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I implemented Google sign-in in many methods. Why Google is using some deprecated methods?

[One Tap sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials)
startIntentSenderForResult() is deprecated
onActivityResult is deprecated

FireBase assistant:
[image: Android Studio FireBase assistant]
onActivityResult is deprecated

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android
onActivityResult is deprecated

Do you know any non-deprecated method for Google sign-in?

Answer (score 0):

> Why Google is using some deprecated methods?

It's because they didn't update the documentation, but most likely they will in the near future.

> onActivityResult is deprecated

You're correct [onActivityResult is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative) in favor of [registerForActivityResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultCaller#registerForActivityResult(androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract%3CI,O%3E,androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback%3CO%3E)).

If you want to try using Jetpack Compose, which I personally recommend, then the following resource will definitely help:

- [How to authenticate to Firebase using Google One Tap in Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d)

Comment: It's true, but it's not only related to documentation. Their library only doesn't have a method for RegisterForActivityResult form.
I faced this problem a lot. Why methods are deprecated before Google corrects them in its self methods?
By the way, you're right. Thanks for your helpful medium link.

Comment: As far as I experienced, when something becomes deprecated, the new approach is released. I didn't see something deprecated without a replacement.

Comment: Hey Ali. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: No thank you  
I think it's the lack of attention by Google.  
I know what you say, but I discussed the effect of depreciation on other classes and behaviors.  
For instance, when I create a fragment by wizard on android studio, an ActivityByResult is created automatically. The Firebase problem is a kind of this one. They didn't consider depreciation effects.
Anyway, thank you for sharing your information.

Comment: You're very welcome, Ali.