# 'startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)' is deprecated <<Java>>

Tags: java, android, xml, api

how to solve this problem

'startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)' is deprecated

here is for my MainActivity.java
`

```
package com.example.praktikump10;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btnMoveActivity;
    private Button btnMoveWithDataActivity;
    private Button btnDialPhone;
    private Button btnMoveWithObject;
    private Button btnMoveForResult;
    private TextView tvResult;
    private int REQUEST_CODE = 100;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnMoveActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_move_activity);
        btnMoveActivity.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnMoveWithDataActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_move_activity_data);
        btnMoveWithDataActivity.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnDialPhone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dial_number);
        btnDialPhone.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnMoveWithObject = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_move_activity_object);
        btnMoveWithObject.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnMoveForResult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_move_for_result);
        btnMoveForResult.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_move_activity:
                Intent moveIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MoveActivity.class);
                startActivity(moveIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.btn_move_activity_data:
                Intent moveWithDataIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MoveWithDataActivity.class);
                moveWithDataIntent.putExtra(MoveWithDataActivity.EXTRA_NAME, "Hafidz Izdihar Muslim\n");
                moveWithDataIntent.putExtra(MoveWithDataActivity.EXTRA_AGE, 20);
                startActivity(moveWithDataIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.btn_dial_number:
                String phoneNumber = "087878336770";
                Intent dialPhoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
                startActivity(dialPhoneIntent);
                break;

            case R.id.btn_move_activity_object:
                Person mPerson = new Person();
                mPerson.setName("DicodingAcademy");
                mPerson.setAge(5);
                mPerson.setEmail("academy@dicoding.com");
                mPerson.setCity("Bandung");
                Intent moveWithObjectIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MoveWithObjectActivity.class);
                moveWithObjectIntent.putExtra(MoveWithObjectActivity.EXTRA_PERSON, mPerson);
                startActivity(moveWithObjectIntent);
                break;

            case R.id.btn_move_for_result:
                Intent moveForResultIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MoveForResultActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(moveForResultIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
                break;

        }
    }
    protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == MoveForResultActivity.RESULT_CODE) {
                int selectedValue = data.getIntExtra(MoveForResultActivity.EXTRA_SELECTED_VALUE, 0);
                tvResult.setText("Hasil : " + selectedValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

and this is my activity_main.xml

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.praktikump10.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_move_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Pindah Activity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_move_activity_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Pindah Activity Dengan Data" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_dial_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Dial a Number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_move_activity_object"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Pindah Activity dengan Object" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_move_for_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Pindah Activity untuk Result" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hasil"
        android:textSize="24sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

`

this is for my MoveForResultActivity.java
`

```
package com.example.praktikump10;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.praktikump10.R;

public class MoveForResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button btnChoose;
    private RadioGroup rgNumber;
    public static String EXTRA_SELECTED_VALUE = "extra_selected_value";
    public static int RESULT_CODE = 110;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_move_for_result);
        btnChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_choose);
        btnChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        rgNumber = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg_number);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_choose) {
            if (rgNumber.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != 0) {
                int value = 0;
                switch (rgNumber.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                    case R.id.rb_50:
                        value = 50;
                        break;
                    case R.id.rb_100:
                        value = 100;
                        break;
                    case R.id.rb_150:
                        value = 150;
                        break;
                    case R.id.rb_200:
                        value = 200;
                        break;
                }
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                resultIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SELECTED_VALUE, value);
                setResult(RESULT_CODE, resultIntent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

activity_move_for_result.xml

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.praktikump10.MoveForResultActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Pilih angka yang kamu suka" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_50"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="50" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_100"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="100" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_150"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="150" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_200"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="200" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_choose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pilih" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`

why the

'startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)' is deprecated

on MainActivity.java

any answer i really appreciated

thank you for the valueable answer...

Comment: this is not a 'problem', it's a notification. You should go to the documentation of that class and method, it should tell you what to use instead. Being deprecated means: it has been replaced by a better solution, will no longer be maintained, and might be removed in a future version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)