# I use "startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);" but startActivityForResult is deprecated

Tags: android, bluetooth, deprecated

I'm following developer android tutorial about Bluetooth and when it comes to configuration part, it says that the following code must be used

```
if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

but it says that startActivityForResult is deprecated and I have no clue how it could be changed .

I tried using  registerForActivityResult but I don`t know very well how it works.

Comment: Strange. A bit of googling will give you hundred examples.

Comment: Maybe this is what you need. Good luck.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63654043/17567905

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way
Note: this code is in `KOTLIN`  `JAVA` version is also below it

Declare variable

```
var launchData: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>? = null
```

instead of `onActivityResult`, in `onCreate` mention before opening new Activity

```
launchData =
 registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
            {
                if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (it.data != null) {
                        it.data.let { obj ->
                           var detail =   obj?.getStringExtra("details")
                                 // or whatever your result keys are
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

instead of `startActivityForResult`

```
Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE).also {
                launchData!!.launch(it)
            }
```

`JAVA`

Variable Declaration

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launchData = null;
```

in onCreate

```
launchData= registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            // There are no request codes
                            Intent data = result.getData();
                            data.getStringExtra("details");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

result callback

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        launchData.launch(enableBtIntent);
```