# ActivityResult result always zero: giving permissions with new method since startActivityForResult is deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, onactivityresult

I am extending support to an old app to Android 13 and I am seeing a lot of changes.
First off, I've noticed that `startActivityForResult` is deprecated since Google decided to change how to handle permission requests and results.

Here there are few examples: [OnActivityResult method is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative) but honestly I did quite catch how the new way works.
Only got that it seems that uses an Observer pattern.

This is how I am currently asking for overlay permissions:

```
   private void askForSystemOverlayPermission() {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            //If the draw over permission is not available open the settings screen
            //to grant the permission.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                //Permission is not available. Display error text.
                errorToastDrawOverOtherApp();
                finish();
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

This is how I've updated my code:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLaunch = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    System.out.println("Code:"+result.getResultCode());
                    if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_CODE_1) {
                        // ToDo : Do your stuff...

                    } else if(result.getResultCode() == RESULT_CODE_2) {
                        // ToDo : Do your stuff...
                    }
                }
            });

if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            activityResultLaunch.launch(intent);
        }
```

but like mentioned I am getting always a result = 0. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your `onActivityResult` didn't check the resultCode but you check for it in the new  `ActivityResultLauncher` approach? How about just checking `Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)` again, do it give the same result?

Answer (score 0):

> This is how I am currently asking for overlay permissions

You are using `startActivityForResult()`. [That `Intent` action is not documented to return a result](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/Settings?hl=en#action_manage_overlay_permission).

> I am getting always a result = 0

That `Intent` action is not documented to return a result, so `0` is the expected value.

If you are expecting something akin to `DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE` from your earlier code, that is not how `ActivityResultContracts` works. `DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE` is a *request* code, not a *result* code. And, you will note that you are not supplying a request code, because that is handled internally by `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult`.

Comment: Yes, I did not supply a request code because I have noticed that ActivityResult only provide a result code and not a request code to compare. So the code is enough for simply checking and requesting overlay permissions?

Comment: @JaneLilep: Personally, I would not use `startActivityForResult()` or `ActivityResultContracts` for an `Intent` action that does not return a result. Whether you choose to do so or not is up to you.

Comment: Please then show me a better approach for checking and requesting (in case not already granted) for overlay permissions and post notifications permissions.

Comment: please tell me if I should post a new question since this was specifically about the result.

Comment: @JaneLilep: `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` [is a `dangerous` permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission?hl=en#POST_NOTIFICATIONS), and you can use `ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission` for that.